# Google Play Services API code outside of an activity?

Tags: android, google-play-services

When implementing the Google Play Services Api into an app. All of the docs and tutorials have all the code being called from the activity.

I would like to break it out into smaller classes that I call inside the activity.

Is this bad practice? If not, how can I make it work in a non-Activity class?

Comment: well you need callback that only an activity has so you really cant do this. if you are trying to cut down code what you can do is create an activity that only handels google play service and have your activity extend that activity

Comment: Well I feel like a real dumb dumb for not thinking of that. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way for your code to participate in the activity lifecycle without hardcoding method calls is to use Fragments.

In GoogleApiClient we do have the [`enableAutoManage()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder.html#enableAutoManage(android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity,%20int,%20com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener)) method on the GoogleApiClient.Builder that enables Google Play services code to do most of the management for you. This can be used if your app supports a single Google Account using GoogleApiClient at a single time. We plan to publish a sample very soon showing this functionality.

You should know there is a bug that we'll fix shortly in automanage functionality that prompts app users for OAuth consent twice if they reject it the first time. If you implement this now the fix will be free when you pickup the newer Google Play services client library.

Comment: it'd be great to update the answer when that sample get released.

Comment: What about the case where I have 2 different GoogleApiClients (Drive and Feedback) - must I use the same Activity superclass to manage both of them?

Comment: No, just use the autoManage method that allows you to specify a clientID; then specify a different clientId for each.

Answer (score 0):

*would like to break it out into smaller classed that I instead call in the activity.*

Do you mean [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) (which you should be using)? Or another type of class?

Inside of a class that extends `Fragment`, simply call `getActivity()` or `getSupportActivity()` to use code that requires a `Context`, or code that must be called from an `Activity`.

If this is code that does not extend Fragment, then you need to add a `Context` variable inside of it. Example constructor (args representing any other object you might need to pass in):

`public MyClass(Object args, Context context)
{
   ...
   mContext = context;
}`

So, when you're constructing your Object in the Activity, you'll write:

`MyClass foo = new MyClass(args, this);`

Then, when you want to call Activity-specific code, you'll call:
`mContext.activitySpecificCode();`

If these classes persist with the creation of a new Activity **you'll have to replace the old Context. A Context object is only valid for the specific instance of the specific Activity it was taken from.**

Comment: If this case, as recommended, we have connect and disconnect to `GoogleApiClient` on a specific lifecycle of an activity such as `onResume` and `onPause`! How are you going to manage that?