# Builder (android.content.Context) In builder cannot be appllied to?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement Google Places API into my app and I'm currently getting this in my error log when trying to run the application.

```
Error:(23, 28) error: no suitable constructor found for Builder(menu_1_fragment)
constructor Builder.Builder(Context,ConnectionCallbacks,OnConnectionFailedListener) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Builder.Builder(Context) is not applicable
(actual argument menu_1_fragment cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
```

Now i'm trying to implement Google maps into a fragment that I have created that will display my app. I also want to include places API, Do I need to create a separate class for google maps or can I include this code like i'm currently doing into my fragment class?

```
    public class menu_1_fragment  extends Fragment {
    MapView mapView;
    GoogleMap map;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1_layout, container, false);
        //--Snippet
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, 0, this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

The error is occurring on `.Builder(this)`

Edit: Modified code

```
`package com.examples.blahblah.blahblah;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;


public class menu_1_fragment  extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    MapView mapView;
    GoogleMap map;

    private Context mContext;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(final Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mContext = activity;
    }




    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1_layout, container, false);
        //--Snippet
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(mContext )
                .enableAutoManage(this, 0, this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
`
```

The new error is now occurring on

```
   .enableAutoManage(this, 0, this)
```

and telling me it's the wrong first argument type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need `activity` `context`. so try with this.

in your Fragment class.

```
private Context mContext
@Override
public void onAttach(final Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mContext = activity;
} 
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1_layout, container, false);
    //--Snippet
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
            .Builder(mContext )
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    return v;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Update :

I had to remove `.enableAutoManage(this,0,this);`

for more info, you can visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988146/google-play-services-api-code-outside-of-an-activity)

Comment: Okay I've so far used your example and it sort of works however I'm sure I'm probably implementing it wrong. I've updated my orginal post to include what it now looks like.

Comment: Is their any reason '.enableAutoManage(this, 0, this)' is now telling me it has a wrong first argument type?

Comment: I would move this to onViewCreated and you don't need to save the Context, just use getActivity(). onViewCreated() will always be called after onAttach().

Comment: hmm okay it seems to be giving me the dame error after moving it to onViewCreate() dang!

Comment: @JohnathonStarge onAttach is deprecated, meaning you have to download the original code from github. The above answer involves a lot of coding. The answer below is neat, does not involve any downloads or too many lines.

Answer (score 2):

your `Fragment` is not implementing the  interface needed. With `this` as third parameter you are declaring that your `Fragment` is an object of a class required by the method itself. The builder is also expecting a `Context` object as first parameter and not an instance of `Fragment`, which you can retrieve with `getActivity()`